# Python 3 and BeautifulSoup 4 searching a word on dictionary site and returning translations

Tags: python, web, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have recently followed this(http://blog.dispatched.ch/2009/03/15/webscraping-with-python-and-beautifulsoup/) tutorial on web scraping with python and beautifulsoup. Unfortunately, this tutorial was written with a 2.x version of python while I am using verion 3.2.3 of python as to focus learning a language version which is still developing for the future. My program retrieves, opens, reads and enters the search term on web page just fine(as far as I can tell) but it doesn't enter the

`for result in results`

loop so nothing is collected and printed. I think this may have to do with how I have assigned results but I am unsure of how to fix it. Here's my code:
`

```
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import string
import sys

user_agent = 'Mozilla/5 (Solaris 10) Gecko'
headers = {'user-agent' : user_agent}

url = "http://www.dict.cc";

values = {'s' : 'rainbow'}
data = urllib.parse.urlencode(values)
data = data.encode('utf-8')
request = urllib.request.Request(url, data, headers)
response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
the_page = response.read()

pool = BeautifulSoup(the_page)
results = pool.find_all('td', attrs = {'class' : 'td7n1'})

source = ''
translations = []

for result in results:
    word = ''
    for tmp in result.find_all(text = True):
        word += " " + unicode(tmp).encode("utf-8")
    if source == '':
        source = word
    else:
        translations.append((source, word))
for translation in translations:
    print ("%s => %s", translation[0], translation[1])
```

Comment: It seems that you have a typo. I looked into the page source code and there is a `class` attribute with `td7nl` value, but not with `td7n1`.

Comment: wow, how embarrassing... thank you for pointing that out